# Why is "body" missing from certain inbox items?

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2, documentation, inbox

I have run into some confusion over the presence of the `body` attribute in an [`inbox-item`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/inbox-item) returned by the [`/inbox`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox) method.

When `item_type` is set to `"careers_invitations"`, the `body` attribute appears to be missing even if the current filter specifically includes it. According to the documentation:

> ```
> answer_id              integer, refers to an answer
>                        may be absent
>
> body                   string
>                        unchanged in unsafe filters
>
> comment_id             integer, refers to a comment
>                        may be absent
> ```
>
> <sup>* emphasis mine</sup>

As you can see, some of the other fields "may be absent" but there is no such warning next to `body`, implying that it will always be present - which appears not to be the case.

Can either the `body` be added to all items or the documentation updated please?

**Note:** I have a URL that demonstrates this problem if you are unable to reproduce it - but for privacy reasons, I cannot post it here.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation was updated sometime in the last 2 years and [the API docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/inbox-item) (version 2.2) now state that the property may be absent:

[image: absence of body is not body of absence]