# The tags array is missing from answer results

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, tags, answers

I'm probably missing something very obvious but it seems like [`/users/{ids}/answers`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users) forgets to include the `tags` badge in the resulting [answer object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer):

> tags (2.1) an array of strings

Nowhere does this mention that it *may be absent*. So, I gather that it must be included with every query that I make to it. And yes, I'm using the appropriate filter.

Interesting behavior: Sometimes, I do see the item, but not always.

[Here's a demo of the bug](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users#pagesize=10&order=desc&sort=activity&ids=3980929&filter=!LUcFBIwWzWPWZPCMve40C.&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

I read [somewhere](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/absent-fields) that fields with *null* values are excluded, but I always understood that to mean fields marked with *may be absent* only.

So, is this a bug?

---

---

Editor's note:  This appears to be *similar*, but not the same as the bug: [The answer object returns an empty array for tags](https://stackapps.com/questions/7213/the-answer-object-returns-an-empty-array-for-tags).  The workaround there does not work in this bug's case.

Comment: Seems that the same problem exists with the [body tag](https://stackapps.com/questions/3869/why-is-body-missing-from-certain-inbox-items?rq=1) and [another one](https://stackapps.com/questions/4554/the-reputation-change-field-is-missing-from-the-reputation-results-on-some-cw-po?rq=1).

Comment: Confirmed.  This is a close cousin to [this bug](https://stackapps.com/questions/7213/the-answer-object-returns-an-empty-array-for-tags), but removing the `body_markdown` properties does not fix it in your case.  ... I recommend that you filter out all but the barest minimum needed for your app.

Comment: @BrockAdams That's really a dupe. Weird that I didn't find it. I'll see if I can without losing usability. Can this theoretically happen with every JSON tag?

Comment: That's not a dupe, since the workaround for it (and another dupe) does not work in your case.  ... For every JSON tag?  Theoretically -- of course!  In real life, don't go borrowing trouble.  If you see a bug, report it.  Otherwise, "Trust but verify".